# Which is better VB6 to .NET converter?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, vb6-migration

Is the VB6 to .NET upgrade wizard included in VS2008 better than the one in VS2005?

UPDATE: I ran the same VB6 code through both upgrade wizards and VS2008 produced far less reported issues in the ugprade report.  The upgrade wizard in VS2008 must be an improved version.

Answer (score 1):

Both VS2005 and VS2008 use the same convertion utility.

Comment: Hi Craig, They are same. You'll just find if your using VS2008 that you'll be using a more updated and forgiving framework.

Comment: How can they be the same if they produce a different number of reported issues?